# Tar - Remove Common Prefix When Creating Archive

Tags: linux, filesystems, tar, archiving

I am attempting to tar up the contents of a root file system, located at `$rootfs`.  The problem is, when I try to `tar -c $rootfs > $dest`, the directories between my current directory and the actual file system remain.  So instead of `etc/fstab`, I have `fun/rootfs/path/etc/fstab` when `rootfs=fun/rootfs/path`, for every single file.

I know about `--strip`, but the problem is that `$rootfs` is a relative-path variable, so I don't know how many directories are between the file system and my current directory.  I can't `cd` for a similar reason; `$dest` is a relative-path variable and I have to stay in the current directory to create the archive in the proper location.

Is there a way I can ignore the `rootfs` path when creating the archive?

Answer (score 2):

You could generate the listing of files relative to the `$rootfs` path and then use `-C $rootfs -T <file-of-filenames>` to create the archive. You cannot use a wildcard to generate the list of files on the tar command line as that will not complete correctly. You could use something like find or ls to do it though.

Answer (score 2):

I’m not sure I understand the question, but how about

```
(cd "$rootfs"; tar -c .) > "$dest"
```

so the `tar` runs in the `$rootfs` directory,
but `$dest` is created relative to the current directory.